# How to run an asp.net core application in docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm completelly new to .Net Core and Docker.

I created a project in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and selected docker to run. My objective is to study about .Net Core and Docker.
In my test app I use `Rotativa.AspNetCore`.

The problem is:
 - When I run the project using IIS Express, everything works.
 - When I run using docker, the project stops when I call a function in `Rotativa.AspNetCore`.

The line throwing error is:

```cs
return new ViewAsPdf("views/relatorios/render.cshtml", vm);
```

It works when debuging with IIS Express, but fails using Docker.

I know that, in this moment, `Rotativa.AspNetCore` calls `wkhtmltopdf.exe`, maybe the problem is in this call.

Here is my dockerfile, It was automatically generated:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Internacional/Internacional.csproj", "Internacional/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Internacional/Internacional.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Internacional"
RUN dotnet build "Internacional.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Internacional.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Internacional.dll"]
```

Whats wrong with my setup?

Comment: Is this on a Linux Container or Windows? In Docker, check which container you've selected. Because if it is a Linux Container then you have to follow different steps to get Rotativa working.

Comment: It's a Windows container.

Comment: Is the .exe copied to your project with Copy Always? And wkhtmltopdf registered properly in your startup?

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with Docker. The Views are *precompiled* when you publish so the files are no longer there (they're compiled into a .dll).

Comment: @KirkLarkin with linux containers you have to take extra steps to get things working. With Windows containers it should work like it does with IIS, but I suspect the .exe is not copied over.

Comment: I set 'copy always' to wkhtmltopdf.exe, but the response is the same. The exception says:
  Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(string wkhtmlPath, string switches, string html, string wkhtmlExe)

Comment: When switching back to IIS, everything works.

Comment: Please install full IIS and then compare full IIS and IIS Express. I think the cause is that the PDF library does not support full IIS at all, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Hi @LexLi. the problem occurs when I'm using docker to run. When using IIS everything works fine.

Comment: @nico_c could you please give a link for steps to follow on Linux? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The wkhtmltopdf does not work under the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet, because that based on nanoserver.

The nanoserver is headless, so the OS does not support GUI. And driver printer is not installed in the OS.

Switch the base image to the mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore.

Comment: Just the "base" address or the "build" address too?

Comment: @AndySchmitt Use the base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore instead of mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet. And do not forget to install runtimes for dotnet and aspnet into the image based on the mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore.